# Laptop not booting up after turning off “Secure Boot”

Tags: secure-boot

First of all, I just installed Ubuntu on my old Laptop. I had Windows on it before.

Long story short, I need to disable Secure Boot. But whenever I try to do it, when I power my (Toshiba) Laptop up, the Screen just goes black and stays like that. You can still hear that the Laptop is running, the screen is just black.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a grub menu if you hold down a key at boot? (Single OS does not display one by default).  Did you try nomodeset on the linux line (type e at the grub menu to edit and add at quiet splash).  Sounds like a video problem, what video card do you have?

Comment: I can access the grub menu. When I type in nomodeset, the screen just stays purple. Additionally, when I mistype a parameter, the laptop freezes at "press any key.